# Interstitial ad showing only for once - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I'm trying to show interstitial ad on every 3rd click (basically after certain number of clicks) On first 3rd click, it shows interstitial ad perfectly but after that it throws the following error

ad has not been loaded or has already been disposed.

```
  bool _isLoaded = false;
  InterstitialAd? interstitialAd;
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    showInterstitialAd();
  }

  void showInterstitialAd(){
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: "ad_id",
        request: const AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
            onAdLoaded: (ad) {
              _isLoaded = true;
              interstitialAd=ad;

              interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
                  onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad){
                    print('ad dismissed');
                    interstitialAd!.dispose();
                  },
                  onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, adError){
                    print('ad failed');
                    interstitialAd!.dispose();
                  }
              );
            },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
              interstitialAd!.dispose();
            }
        ));
  }


// show ad when counter is equal to 3
void onTap (){
           if(_isLoaded && counter == 3){
                interstitialAd!.show();
                counter = 0;
           } else {
                counter ++;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rename your `showInterstitialAd` to `loadInterstitialAd` (because method only load and prepare ads) and call it after `counter = 0;`

Should look like this:

```
if(_isLoaded && counter == 3){
      interstitialAd!.show();
      counter = 0;
      loadInterstitialAd();
    } else {
        counter ++;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't worked! The same error is still showing up "ad has not been loaded or has already been disposed."

Comment: sort it out! I also had to set the interstitialAd to null along with disposing it! Thank you

Comment: @shakky don't forget to mark as answer, is it was useful